# 500 Internal Server Error when generating JWT token using Knock gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, jwt

I am trying to authenticate my API requests with JWT Web Tokens, using the Knock gem in my Ruby on Rails application.

I did what the readme stated and modified the `routes.rb` file.

After that, I tried using cURL to get a token to see if everything was working. I typed `curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"auth": {"email": "test@mail.com", "password": "password"}}' localhost:3000/auth/auth_token` (Knock is mounted to "/auth" and the user exists).

However, I get a 500 internal server error and this stack trace:

```
`Processing by Knock::AuthTokenController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"auth"=>{"email"=>"test@mail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "test@mail.com"]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "test@mail.com"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 104ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)`

`TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
  jwt (1.5.2) lib/jwt.rb:73:in 'digest'
  jwt (1.5.2) lib/jwt.rb:73:in 'sign_hmac'
  jwt (1.5.2) lib/jwt.rb:34:in 'sign'
  jwt (1.5.2) lib/jwt.rb:98:in 'encoded_signature'
  jwt (1.5.2) lib/jwt.rb:108:in 'encode'
  knock (1.4.1) app/model/knock/auth_token.rb:13:in 'initialize'
  knock (1.4.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:17:in 'new'
  knock (1.4.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:17:in 'auth_token'
  knock (1.4.1) app/controllers/knock/auth_token_controller.rb:8:in 'create'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.5) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.5) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

I have no idea what's causing this. The weirder thing is that I am working with a friend and he is able to generate a token, even though we are on the same branch and the environment **SHOULD** be the same (apparently it isn't, but I don't know where we differ).

I have google around, but no-one seems to have the same problem (or maybe I am googling for the wrong thing).

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and sqlite for the database, if that is of any help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually managed to get it to work.

What I did was

- Uninstall Ruby (removed any references to it system wide, cleaned packages, updated everything and did `dist-upgrade`
- Reinstalled Ruby (I use rbenv, but it should be the same with whatever you want)
- Since I was working in a new branch of the project, I deleted the project folder and cloned it again from git
- Reinstalled `bundle` after correctly configuring Ruby (I followed the guide in rbenv's github page)
- Ran `bundle` in my project, it got all the gems that I needed
- Configured my secret for the rails server (`rake secret` and paste that in `config/secret.yml`)

After this it was working.
My best guess is that either I missconfigured the server or I had a corrupt gem.